# How can I set alias for table MySQL table in Ruby On Rails 3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I set an alias for a MySQL table in Ruby On Rails 3?

```
data = TUP.all :select => 
  "DATE(tup.created_at) as date
   , ROUND(SUM(fo_count)/#{authors_count}) AS followers"
   ,:joins => "INNER JOIN tlsts AS tl ON tl.user_id = tup.user_id"
   ,:conditions => condition
```

What I mean is the following: Where I can set the alias **tup** for table TwitterUserProfile in this code?
For what parameter **:from=>**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_table_name :table_name` in model which you want to affiliate that table with. For e.g.:

```
  class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name :user_roles # Add user_roles table to UserRole model so, you can make query to that table like: @user_roles = UserRole.all/ @user_role = UserRole.find(params[:id]) etc.
  end
```